# Hive query to extract part of the string using regexp

Tags: sql, regex, hadoop, hive, hiveql

Need `Hive` Query using `regexp_extract` to extract a part of a Field (type String).

The value in it is colon-separated

```
Field String: 
ID(1001):10|Value(1002):8|Name(xyz):7
```

Need to extract the value after `:`

```
>ID -> 10  
>Value -> 8  
>Name -> 7
```

Tried using `regexp_extract` and could not get the output.

Comment: Please share your attempt using `regexp_extract`

Comment: @DigvijayS I am able to pull the value inside the parenthesis ,regexp_extract("ID(1001):10|Value(1002):8|Name(xyz):7"," Value\\(([^)]+)\\",1) as after1

Answer (score 1):

Remove strings in parenthesis, convert to map and use map['key'] to get fields:

```
select m['ID'] as id, m['Value'] as value, m['Name'] as Name 
  from (select str_to_map(regexp_replace('ID(1001):10|Value(1002):8|Name(xyz):7','\\(.*?\\)',''),'\\|',':') as m
       )s;
```

Result:

```
id      value   name
10      8       7
```

Using regexp only:

```
SELECT regexp_extract(t.col,'(?i)ID.*?:(\\d+)\\|',1)    as ID,
       regexp_extract(t.col,'(?i)Value.*?:(.?+)\\|',1)  as Value,
       regexp_extract(t.col,'(?i)Name.*?:(.?+)\\|*',1)  as Name
FROM (SELECT 'ID(1001):10|Value(1002):8|Name(xyz):7' AS col) t;
```

Result:

```
id      value   name
10      8       7
```

Answer (score 0):

if you could use `SPLIT` function, it would be very easy. As an example:

```sql
SELECT split(split(t.col, '\\|')[0],'\\:')[1] AS ID,
       split(split(t.col, '\\|')[1], '\\:')[1] AS Value,
       split(split(t.col, '\\|')[2], '\\:')[1] AS Name
FROM (SELECT 'ID(1001):10|Value(1002):8|Name(xyz):7' AS col) t;
```

```
+-----+--------+-------+--+
| id  | value  | name  |
+-----+--------+-------+--+
| 10  | 8      | 7     |
+-----+--------+-------+--+
```